# Phaser js memory leak

Tags: phaser-framework

I am using phaser 2.4.3, in my shut down I have destroyed and set the variables to null. Still when I replay (by calling the state again) for 5 or 6 times chrome browser crashes due to memory issues.

eg usage in shutdown function:

```
if (this.backgroundBg) {
    this.backgroundBg.destroy();
    this.backgroundBg = null;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a "loader" state where you pre-load all your assets? Maybe the destroy() function also deletes the cached sprite so you have to reload the asset again?

Comment: Yes, I have a separate preloader state also. The issue was not with Phaser, in gameover state I was using another script which was creating the issue. So issue is solved now.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, the issue was not with Phaser, in gameover state I was using another script which was creating the issue. So issue is solved now.

Comment: Just to let you know, when you change states all sprites should be automatically destroyed. So you shouldn't have to do manual cleanup in your shutdown function. To test this, create a Sprite as a static variable and attempt to reference it in the next state. Key variables inside it should be destroyed, and the object itself will eventually be GC'd (if you didn't hold onto the static reference).